# Setting shadow on textView in Android not working

Tags: java, android, textview

I've tried searching on stack overflow and on google to see if there are any mistake I'm making, but I am not currently aware that I'm doing anything incorrectly. I don't see any difference after applying the shadow layer. Below is what I've tried:

```
TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

textv.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);    
textv.setShadowLayer(25, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
texttv.setShadowLayer(1.5f, -1, 1, Color.LTGRAY);
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

I want my text to have a black border around its characters because it is being displayed on top of an image.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Soft Shadow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/TransparentGrey"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="1.5" />
</LinearLayout>
```